# Restlet 2.3 How to set temp directory

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, restlet-2.0

I am using Restlet 2.3 with the Jetty ext. How do you set the `temp` directory that the `jar` is unpacked to?

Using just jetty in another project it can be achieved using:

```
private void resetTempDirectory(WebAppContext context, String currentDir) {
        File tmpDir = new File(currentDir, ".tmp");
        tmpDir.deleteOnExit();
        tmpDir.mkdir();
        context.setTempDirectory(tmpDir);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find here all the supported parameters for the Jetty server connector: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jse/ext/. It appears that there is no parameter for the temp directory.

For information here is the way to configure a server connector using context: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/base/connectors.

I have a look at the Jetty extension. Restlet leverages the class `Server`  and `JettyServerCall` to respectively create the Jetty server and handle requests. I can't see any use of a class `WebAppContext`.

That said, I'm not sure Jetty / Restlet unpack things ;-) Could you give me hints about the way you configure / use Jetty in your other project? Thanks!

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Yep, the other project is in fact packaged as a `war` with embedded jetty. The `war` is added to jetty using `WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(warFile, "/");`. It is possible that it only gets unpacked because its a `war`.

Comment: Yes, in fact, Restlet doesn't use war file for its Jetty extension. The Jetty server is embedded within the Restlet "application". To embed a Restlet application, you can use the servlet extension and such configuration can be done at the container level (jetty for example).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to unpack a file to a temporary directory, you can simply use the "java.io.tmpdir" system property.

When you run a Restlet application using the Jetty extension, you are not running the Jetty's servlet container, but the part of Jetty that handle sockets. Just consider you are running a program inside a JVM.